# Make objects with a matching property join in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make two objects join in the following way.

I have these arrays.

Sets:

```
const sets = [
{
    set_id: 1,
    title: 'Mugs'
},
{
    set_id: 2,
    title: 'Phone Cases'
},
{
    set_id: 3,
    title: 'Pillows'
}
];
```

and products:

```
const products = [
{
    product_id: 101,
    title: 'Funny Pillow',
    set: 3
},
{
    product_id: 102,
    title: 'Motivational Mug',
    set: 1
},
{
    product_id: 103,
    title: 'Cool Phone Case',
    set: 2
}
];
```

My goal here is to join a **product** to its matching **set** using code.

So a **set** would look something like this.

```
{
set_id: 1,
title: 'Mugs',
products: [
    {   product_id: 102,
        title: 'Motivational Mug',
        set: 1
    }
]
}
```

I've been trying this for hours, thanks in advance!

Comment: So far i've tried a lot of things, i think the closest one was:



`const joinArrays = new Map(products.map((p) => [ p.id, p.set ])),
    res = sets.map((s) => Object.assign({ prods: joinArrays.get(s.id) }, s));
    
console.log(res)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do `map` on `sets` and `filter` on `products` by `set_id`

```js
const sets = [
  {
    set_id: 1,
    title: "Mugs",
  },
  {
    set_id: 2,
    title: "Phone Cases",
  },
  {
    set_id: 3,
    title: "Pillows",
  },
];

const products = [
  {
    product_id: 101,
    title: "Funny Pillow",
    set: 3,
  },
  {
    product_id: 102,
    title: "Motivational Mug",
    set: 1,
  },
  {
    product_id: 103,
    title: "Cool Phone Case",
    set: 2,
  },
];

const res = sets.map((set) => ({
  ...set,
  products: products.filter((product) => product.set === set.set_id),
}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```